# django aggregate sum of subgroup maximums

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following simplified setup in Django, using MySQL:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class MyTable(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['category', 'date']
```

And a query set comprised of the following sample data for `MyTable`:

```
date        category_id amount
2017-12-01  3           2
2018-01-01  1           100
2018-02-01  1           50
2018-03-01  2           2000
2018-04-01  2           4000
2018-05-01  3           2
2018-06-01  3           1
```

What I ultimately want is a way to get the sum of the `amount`s corresponding to the latest `date` for each `category`. To illustrate:

- The latest `date` for `category_id` 1 is 2018-02-01, where the `amount` is 50;
- The latest `date` for `category_id` 2 is 2018-04-01, where the `amount` is 4000;
- The latest `date` for `category_id` 3 is 2018-06-01, where the `amount` is 1;
- 50 + 4000 + 1 = 4051

I'm trying to figure how to get the value 4051 through an aggregate call to this queryset. I've tried every combination of "values", "annotate" and "aggregate" I could think of and nothing gets the desired result. The following gets me the latest date for each `category`, but every time I try to get the sum of the corresponding `amount`s, it calculates it on *every* `amount` instead of just the maximums.

```
MyTable.objects.values('category').annotate(Max('date'))
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible through Django's ORM? I posted another question about what the MySQL syntax would be for this exact example, but can't get that to apply to a Django query set either.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need some data structures to achieve this please take a look at the below answer this if Djnago ORM  or sql does not meet your requirement(unable to write)

```
l=[]
x=MyTable.objects.values('category').annotate(date=Max('date'))
for y in x:
    qq= MyTable.objects.get(category_id=y.get(category),date=y.get(date))
    l=l+qq.amount
total_amount = sum(l)
print(total_amount)
```

Comment: While I'd been hoping to do this exclusively at the database level for performance reasons, it seems your answer is the only way to achieve this using Django's ORM and MySQL (without altering any of its settings), so I'm marking this as the accepted answer. Thanks for your help!